# light inject - unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi, light-inject

I have an c# interface with multiple implementations & each implementation is taking various dependencies object in its constructor.

In order to achieve DI using LightInjector on web api project, Im registering a 'Func' like below & its working as expected but can't able to unit test it.

Any way I can write the below code in unit testable way?

```
 container.RegisterInstance<Func<IHandler, HandlerType, IHandler>>
        ((handler, type) =>
        {
            IHandler context = null;
            switch (type)
            {
                case HandlerType.Type0:
                    context = new Type0(orderHandler, container.GetInstance<IUtilityLogic>());
                    break;
                case HandlerType.Type1:
                    context = new Type1(orderHandler, container.GetInstance<IUtilityLogic>(), container.GetInstance<IShipmentLogic>());
                    break;
                case HandlerType.Type2:
                    context = new Type2(orderHandler);
                    break;
                case HandlerType.Type3:
                    context = new Type3(orderHandler, container.GetInstance<IUtilityLogic>());
                    break;
                case HandlerType.Type4:
                    context = new Type4(orderHandler, container.GetInstance<IUtilityLogic>(), container.GetInstance<IShipmentLogic>(), container.GetInstance<Func<string, string, ICache>>());
                    break;
                default:
                    context = null;
                    break;
            }

            return context;
        });
```

Comment: I don't think, you should unit test container.... In my opinion you should write integration test for that functionality.

Comment: Since, here test container having logic, I believe it is good to get it unit tested.